# How to setting charset to utf8 when create schema in scala slick 3.2?

Tags: slick

I'm use `db.run(DBIOAction.seq(chartRef.schema.create))` to create a table for mysql.But it charset show as latin1.How to make the table's charset as utf8 when create schema?

I have append `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to connection url string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Either set it manually by setting the db collation to UTF-8
2. Try this

   db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?characterEncoding=UTF-8"

Configure URL using this [link](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/database.html#using-a-database-url).

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, I just test second and it not works.Besides, config only notify `db.url`.I have append encoding to utf-8. the `db.default.url` seems not be load with a exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.`.

Comment: try the first one by changing the ddatabase configuration manually

Comment: It works! I'm use `ALTER DATABASE <dn_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: But can I specify a table's charset when I create it in slick?

Comment: Great..There may be a way but why not set it during the creating of table.

Comment: I want to know how to map sql property `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf-8`, in create table sql statement, to slick's ORM code.Besides,  db collation will affact all table's charset rather then one.

Comment: Try setting the property file as :
properties = {
      databaseName = "aaaa"  
      user = "userna"
      password = "passwords"
      serverName = "localhost"
      portNumber="1111"
      characterEncoding="utf8"
      useUnicode=true
    }

Comment: or use the link to configure url. Updated in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142055/discussion-between-learner-and-lorancechen).

Comment: I have test the second method but it not works. Does slick `Table` class has a field can setting the entity table's charset?